# How to "close" from view standard taxonomy page

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I made several taxonomy dictionaries and all of them have terms. I use terms for Views generations. But standart drupal functionalaty lets end-user to enter as URL: "site/dictionary name/term name" and get list of materials which were marked by this term.
How I can "close" this page? I do not want end-user to see my materials by this hack.

Comment: Go to the permissions page and remove the relevant permission from unauthorized users.

Comment: Unfortunatly, there is no such option.

Comment: You can always add this option using hook_menu_alter.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily there is module for that: [Disable Term Node Listings](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_term_node_listings)

> By default, on taxonomy term pages, Drupal will display a list of nodes (teaser build mode) that are tagged with that term. Disable Term Node Listing allows you to selectively disable node listings on taxonomy term pages by vocabulary.
>
> Disable term listings for a particular vocabulary by going to the edit page [/structure/taxonomy/[vocab_machine_name_here]/edit].

Comment: Unfortunatly, I can not find this toggle on taxonomy page. I have there only: name and description fields.

Comment: @user38998 Maybe a silly question, but did you install the module? Below the name and description fields on the /structure/taxonomy/[vocab_machine_name_here]/edit page there should be radio buttons available under the title 'Node listings'.

Answer (score 0):

1) In hook menu alter:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term']['access callback'] = FALSE;
  $items['taxonomy/term/%taxonomy_term/feed']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

2) If you use Panels module:

- enable `Taxonomy term template` page
- create variant with type `HTTP response code`
- chose 403 of 404 `Responce code`